# Adding a Vue.js v-on event to D3 SVG element

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, mouseevent

Is it possible to add a VueJS v-on event to an SVG element in D3?  I want to use the v-on.mouseover functionality to each rectangle element of an SVG.  I am trying to do so by adding `v-on:mouseover="active = !active"` as an attribute in D3, as in the following snippet:

```
h.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(myCSVdata)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('v-on:mouseover', 'active = !active')
  .attr('class', 'bars')
  .append('rect')
```

but D3 seems to strip out the `v-on:` and I am left with

```
<g mouseover="active = !active" class="bars">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here...

```
.attr('v-on:mouseover', 'active = !active')
```

... is that the colon normally defines the namespace, and D3 will think that `v-on` is a namespace.

There is a solution, though: add another colon before it.

```
.attr(':v-on:mouseover', 'active = !active')
//     ^---- extra colon here
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr(':v-on:mouseover', 'active = !active');
  
console.log(div.node())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerald! That does indeed solve the problem of getting the attribute to list correctly.  Sadly vue.js no longer seems to interpret the v-on directive in this context.  I must be on the wrong track as to how to integrate the two.

Comment: Yes, I have a feeling that the attribute would be set, but that it wouldn't work... Unfortunately, I'm not a Vue user. Anyway, now you know that D3 thinks that everything before the colon is the namespace.

Comment: You did answer the question absolutely correctly but I am going to leave it unchecked for a little while in the hope that someone will point me in the right direction.

Comment: In case anyone is  going down this particular rabbit hole, I found my way out through this presentation http://slides.com/pawelgrabarz/es-vue-gee#/ which demonstrates what seems to be the best way to integrate Vue and D3.

Comment: The solution is still working, at least for calling a vue method. Thanks for the hint with the prefix colon.