# How to enable v-on evnt on vue.js objects appended by D3

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, vue.js

I am building a chart with c3, then adding a div on top of this chart using d3:

Please see the working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ldylag/sry4px3b/).

```
var naviChart = d3
  .selectAll("#chart")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "hist-future-btn");
naviChart
  .append("div")
  .text("Hist")
  .attr("class", "hist")
  .attr(":v-on:click", "showHistChart");
```

and even though the code is generated properly (checked via Chrome inspector):

```
<div class="hist" @click="showHistChart">Hist</div>
```

the function `showHistChart` is not called.
I copy-pasted the above line from the Chrome inspector to the bottom of my HTML code and then it works. So we know that d3 generates the code properly but it is not *vue event enabled*

**How to enable `vue.js` on objects added dynamically by `d3.js`?**

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403544/adding-a-vue-js-v-on-event-to-d3-svg-element), with very similar question but it answers only hot to enable *events* on svg elements and opens my question in the comment.

Comment: can you try `.on("click", showHistChart);` instead of `.attr(":v-on:click", "showHistChart");`

Comment: I changed to `.on("click", this.showHistChart)` and works perfect. Thank You

Comment: @VamsiKrishna - you may want to post it as an answer and the John Ovveriron should probably accept it. Otherwise this question is hanging in there as unanswered.

Comment: This is great workaround, but unfortunately this does not answer fully the question. In example if we add dynamically input field, we have to bind it with `v-model`. Or any other `v-for` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer on the [forum.vuejs.org](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-object-generated-by-d3-append-does-not-bind-and-does-not-react-to-events/37207), so sharing here:

@LinusBorg, the Vue.js core team member says:

> Vue can only bind to DOM that it knows about from its template, so the
>   answer is: No, that’s not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `.attr(":v-on:click", "showHistChart");` with `.on("click", this.showHistChart);` where `this.showHistChart` represents a method in the vue instance.